# Would lack of petroleum oil help make planes impossible, or uncompetitive to airships?

Tags: steampunk, airships

In my steampunk world (developed to roughly 1870-1910 levels of technological development), there are no oil deposits and flatlands are highly valuable due to their relative rarity (the entire thing is located on basically a humongous vertical rocky cliff, with only some ledges reaching the sizes of small islands, which are mostly used as strategically important locations for farming).

Since oil is required to make light and powerful enough internal combustion engine be viable, and the land is too valuable to waste on building landing strips - would that be enough to strangle the concept of a heavier than air aircraft in infancy (Other than engineless gliders, maybe?) and not worry that it would displace airships as the most efficient way to travel by air?

Comment: Airships consume *more fuel* that airplanes. (The engines of the airplane are not there to keep it aloft; that's what the wings are for. The engines are there to push the airplane through the air; airships have vaaaaaastly larger cross sections than airplanes.)

Comment: Although the engines pushing/pulling the airplane through the air are what causes *lift* to affect the wings, bringing the plane into the air, so the engine contributes greatly to the plane staying aloft. 

Apologies for the correction - it's pretty critical to aerodynamics and Bernoulli's principal - lift happens when there is airflow passing over and under the wing; that is achieved by speed, and therefore the engine. A glider outsources it's engine, it still needs the same thing. An elastic band would eliminate the "engine" but it's still an external supply of speed to create lift.

Comment: I think, if I understand, you are going to have a sort-of vertical train system moved by balloon. Most movement would be up/down (possibly on some sort of track) and sideways motion would be mostly to maneuver. Seriously not understanding how a giant cliff can have a civilization anything like normal. What about air pressure?

Comment: On short distances probably even conventional steam-powered funiculars, but I don't think this is viable for long stretches of cliff. Imagine having to carve hundreds of kilometers of rock to form a base for a rail. Sounds way easier to just fly over in an airship even if they can't carry as much cargo on them.

Comment: @AlexP Have you actually done a real number-crunch on this, or are you extrapolating it from your beliefs that the engines are not involved in the wings holding up the airplane, and that cross-section is the deciding factor in air resistance?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: An Airbus A340 burns about 50 tonnes of fuel flying 260 passengers from Berlin to New York. The Hindenburg burned 55 tonnes of fuel for the same flight, carrying 70 passengers. The A340 consumes four times less fuel per passenger, and flies about seven times faster. Progress is a good thing.

Comment: @OK, so you didn't make an effort at all, and you're just blurting out the first facts you came to.  You haven't optimized either mode for fuel economy, or even applying the most basic facts about aerodynamic drag.  *"engines don't keep planes aloft"*, I had to know it would only go downhill from there...

Comment: Probably the key driving factor would be how much precious level ground is used up operating planes v airships. A lot of specialist fabric is required in an airship which ultimately has to be "grown".

Comment: If there is no oil where are they getting their lifting gas from? If there is no fuel how are they building any technology?

Comment: @John due to the peculiarity of the setting, getting hydrogen is not that hard.

Comment: @DarthBiomech then why not make hydrogen powered aircraft?

Comment: @John
Because steampunk should have zeppelins, not airplanes, and I need there to be a valid reason for why airplanes were a dead-end in this verse for that technological level.

Comment: @DarthBiomech then just say no one has invented it yet, it took two hundred years after the invention of steam engines to get planes,  if flat land is hard to come by that will make it even harder.

Answer (score 8):

Biodiesel or Alcohol both make *great* fuel for engines, and can be made from any foodstuffs.

It you people can eat, they have the base materials to make fuel.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're strangling the development of engines nicely. :)

However there are also many other moving parts that need to use lubricants like oils in order to operate - doors, gates, anything with a hinge; telescopic sliders in binoculars; gears in wind-up toys and watches; guns guns guns, from flintlock through to fully automatic repeating weapons, etc. If it has two bits of metal touching or scraping together it'll need lubricant.

So for these you may need to investigate some type of substitute.

Perhaps you might like to make your people more agrarian, in which case good old soybeans might be useful:

https://www.resourceefficient.eu/en/good-practice/soybean-oil-lubricant-substitute

On another Stack Exchange, they've discussed this here: [https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/what-happens-if-i-use-vegetable-oil-instead-of-machine-oil-or-grease#:~:text=Oil%2C%20WD40%2C%20or%20any%20petro,a%20bit%20messy%20to%20use](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/what-happens-if-i-use-vegetable-oil-instead-of-machine-oil-or-grease#:%7E:text=Oil%2C%20WD40%2C%20or%20any%20petro,a%20bit%20messy%20to%20use).

I noticed one poster mentioning silicon-based lubricant. So silicon might be a go-er for you. Here's a page I've found helping explain the basics of it: https://www.naturalhandyman.com/iip/infxtra/infsil.html

Of course these bring engines back into play, but maybe you can create a supply/demand problem much easier with these alternatives eg soybeans can only grow in flatland areas, or silicate mining is eroding places to live in the cliffs etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Other oils are not a problem; you just use animal or plant oils.  Or for things like hinges, one of my favorites: graphite paint, with the pigment replaced with graphite powder. It's deliciously slippery without being sticky, so it doesn't collect dust and dirt. Any agricultural supply sells it.

Answer (score 1):

**Engineers will only develop things that work**

The 19th century.. In that period, on Earth, diesel engines were invented. But this invention was feasible *and* successful, *because* it depended on a ready available fuel. There exists no fuel on your planet, so engineers would not imagine/design/draw/build any type of engine that uses it. Problem solved, keep optimistic. There is no need for fuel because nothing uses fuel. In short, as a consequence of your world's limitations, a fossil fuel or biomass fuel  engine design would never have happened.

**Sail powered airships**

A wood-fueled manned balloon was invented in the 18th century. [Lilienthal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Lilienthal) flew a glider in 1891, and on your planet, there will be someone attempting the same thing. Humans always want to fly. Your people may accomplish flight. Actual air transport we accomplished in 30-40 years, using motorized aircraft (Wrights brothers, Blériot, DC-3) but without diesel fuel, that would not have happened. No Hindenburgs either... This airship was just a balloon with some diesel engines mounted on it.

Probably, your airships will require sails at first, like [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50529/could-a-blimp-maneuver-using-a-sail) baby,

[image]

See also WB topic
[How could a sail powered airship work?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8485/how-could-a-sail-powered-airship-work)

**Electric flight**

Modern insights - after 1870 - have found there are *three* energy sources for engines, that is fossil fuel, biomass fuel, *or*.. electricity.

The electromotor could be an option. It will need steel for some of its parts. Steel could be produced manually, or using machines and lots of energy. It needs to be precise. In Sweden, they use machines and energy, but they say they can do it *without* the fossil fuels,

[image]
https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2021/08/sweden-hybrit-first-fossil-free-steel/

What if your steampunks would set up some generators ? wind energy, or tidal energy. Harvest Earth heat.. Solar heat collectors.. or let your people discover fission energy and try the nuclear option to generate electricity. There is no science tag, what about cold fusion ?

Based on electricity, an electric motor will be invented. Next step would be to develop light weight batteries.. and off the cliff you go !  With small aircraft, landing won't be an issue. STOL landings require very little space.

[image]
Earth 2020

Upscaling the electric aircraft to make it an actual means of transport will be an issue to overcome. Nowadays, on Earth, we are about in that stage. We have very agile Pipistrel aircraft: two-seaters. For more passengers or transport, things are in an experimental stage, the electric Cessna Caravan can fly 14 passengers,

[image]

https://robbreport.com/motors/aviation/worlds-largest-electric-airplane-takes-flight-2930460/

**Be patient.. some time it will happen**

We developed electric flight in 120 years or so. Keep in mind developments on your steampunk world, without fuel, could take centuries instead of decades. But they will result in *super-lean* designs, with energy usage efficiency we can only dream of.

Comment: _steam_ punk. Not _cyber_ punk. So you think that overly efficient steam engine can't be used on zeppelins? Even if their lifting force is also higher than it should be?

Comment: edited.. and indeed.. I *supposed* there is no fossil fuel, but you did not mension **coal**. With coal, at least steel production would be a lot easier ! Of course, it depends on the amount, but coal would help development. For aircraft.. you'll need a conversion. Coal as fuel is too heavy to lift and transport as weight.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to [run planes on ethanol](https://www.flightglobal.com/corn-to-run-can-ethanol-be-used-as-a-clean-alternative/71449.article) if not jets. It's a low vibration fuel, and easy enough to make.

Since you want such planes to not be a thing, just have it be common to have birds that love the smell of ethanol and other fuels and will fly at planes which carry it.

Airships can carry fuel tanks deeper inside them and stay safe, be they coal or ethanol.